# How to properly use Mongoose query, Find and update object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is Main Code to look into

```
function update(feed){
//.. do set up
var target = feed.title;
var value = {index: feed.value};

var query = { test: target, 'array.index': {$ne: value.index} },
    update = { $push : {"array" : value} },
    options = { upsert: true, new: true };

Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(docs);
    }
);}
```

(I modified the code to be general. if you need specific code, just ask me to update this post)

I am trying to do **Model.findOneandUpdate** with *upsert: true*.
My code executes when specific event emitted

```
feedparser.on('readable', function() {
    update(this.read());
});
```

Becasue of **'array.index': {$ne: value.index}** query, the code creates new one after the first execution.

Therefore,

> db.collection.find()

returns multiple documents that has same property with different ObjectId.
For Example,

> {"_id":ObjectId("1"), test: "A", array:[{index:"1"}]}
>   {"_id":ObjectId("2"), test: "A", array:[{index:"1"}]}

I want to be the code do

1. Check document exist or not.
2. if Exist, add new value to the Document's array. Also, new value should be unique by **index**.
3. if NOT Exist, create new Document and add new value to new Document's array.

**UPDATE:**
I also try to do it by

```
var doc = Model.findOne({ test: target });

if(doc != null){
    var query = { _id: doc._id, 'array.index': {$ne: value.index} };
    var update = { $push : {"array" : value} };
    var options = {new: true};
    Model.update(query, update, options, function(err, d){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(d);
    });

}else{
    doc = {
        test: target,
        array:[value]
    };

    Model.create(doc, function (err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

This code result in do Nothing.

**UPDATE**
I also try this by

```
Model.findOne({ test:target }, function(err, doc){
    if(doc === null){
        doc = {
            test: target
            arrays:[value]
        };

        Animation.create(doc, {new: true}, function (err, res){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
        });
    }else{
        var query = { _id: doc._id, 'arrays.index': {$ne: value.index} };
        var update = { $push : {"arrays" : value} };
        var options = {new: true};
        Animation.update(query, update, options, function(err, res){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
});
```

But, it create new Document by each different index value.

**UPDATE**

```
var query = { test: target, 'array:index': {$ne: value.index} };
var update = { $push : {'array' : value}};
var options = {new: true};
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, doc){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(doc === null){
        doc = new Model({
            test: target,
            array:[value]
        });
        doc.save();
    }
});
```

It also does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve this problem!
First, the reason why the problem arise is I am trying to do **upsert** with **$ne**.
Here is my code,

```
Animation.findOne({ title: AnimationTitle, team: TeamName }, function(err, result){
        if(err) { throw err; }
        if(result){
            Animation.findOneAndUpdate({ title: AnimationTitle, team: TeamName, 'episodes.number': {$ne: episode.number} }, { $addToSet : {'episodes' : episode}}, {new: true}, function(err, result){
                if(err) { throw err; }
            });
        }else{
            Animation.findOneAndUpdate({ title: AnimationTitle, team: TeamName }, { $addToSet : {'episodes' : episode}}, {new: true, upsert: true}, function(err, result){
                if(err) { throw err; }
            });
        }

    });
```